# Can't change AppleID for iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have an iPhone5C (running iOS10.3.3 - the latest it supports).
I normally use this as a second phone while travelling.

I wanted to let my wife use this on a trip, and login to her AppleID for contacts etc.
The phone currently uses my AppleID (which is also used for family sharing).

Our attempts to login to her AppleID fail with a message that the email is already in use.

We are obviously doing something wrong, but I can't seem to find what I should do.

Comment: Can you add the exact text of the error message, and perhaps a screenshot?